# Setting up separate database for django apps

Tags: python, django, web

I am working on a project. I want the client to populate the apps I've worked on with real data while I'm working on the remaining part of the project. But right now I'm confused on how to go about it. I'm thinking on setting up separate database for each app but I'm a novice in web development, so I don't know if it is a good idea.

I'll also like to get a sample implementation for setting up separate database tables in Django. or if there a better alternative way to do I'll be grateful to know.

Comment: You must have two separate databases. One on your development machine and one in your production server. You must never work directly on your production database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.